# From RGBA to Hex

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to convert a RGBA value (4 values split) to a HEX value.

At the moment, I've this code:

```
int red = Integer.parseInt(colors[0]);
int green = Integer.parseInt(colors[1]);
int blue = Integer.parseInt(colors[2]);
float alpha = Float.parseFloat(colors[3]);
```

So now, I want to get those colors to HEX, so I can use this method to create a Color: `new ColorDrawable(0xFF99CC00)`

Any tips?

Comment: Are you trying to `setBackgroundColor` in android by converting `RGBA` to `HEX` or any other purpose ? tell your actual need.

Comment: I'm trying to convert a RGBA value (4 values split) to a HEX value.

Comment: for what ? set `setBackgroundColor` or any other purpose ?

Comment: so I can use this method to create a Color: new ColorDrawable(0xFF99CC00) so I can pass it into a `ActionBar bar = this.getActionBar();
   bar.setBackgroundDrawable(...)` Basically to create a Drawable

Comment: ColorDrawable() takes an int, see my answer. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/ColorDrawable.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it out:

```
ActionBar bar = this.getActionBar();
String hex = String.format("#%02x%02x%02x%02x", alpha,red, green, blue);
bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor(hex)));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public int toHex(Color color) {
    String alpha = pad(Integer.toHexString(color.getAlpha()));
    String red = pad(Integer.toHexString(color.getRed()));
    String green = pad(Integer.toHexString(color.getGreen()));
    String blue = pad(Integer.toHexString(color.getBlue()));
    String hex = "0x" + alpha + red + green + blue;
    return Integer.parseInt(hex, 16);
}

private static final String pad(String s) {
    return (s.length() == 1) ? "0" + s : s;
}
```

**Usage**

```
int color = toHex(new Color(1f, 1f, 1f, 1f));
```

or you can use

```
Color.argb(a_int, r_int, g_int, b_int);
//(Multiply int value by 255.0f)
```

Answer (score 0):

To Convert rgba to Hexa color:
This function you can use,
rgba value is for example : rgba(255,249,249,0.54)

```
fun rgbaToHexa(color: String): String? {
    try {
        val value = color.removePrefix("rgba(").removeSuffix(")").split(",")
        val red = value[0].toInt()
        val green = value[1].toInt()
        val blue = value[2].toInt()

        val hex = String.format("#%02x%02x%02x", red, green, blue)

        return hex
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        loge("exception:${e.printStackTrace()}")
    }

    return null
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try using the following: 
 http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#argb(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)

Comment: When you have a float alpha 0.0f - 1.0f, simply do something like `int a = (int)(alpha * 255.99);`, or 255 - a.